# django-photologue not loading CSS

Tags: django

I have setup django-photologue, and I am trying to get it to load the default templates. I can get the HTML file loaded, but it won't load any of the CSS (mainly just bootstrap)

When accessing photologue, I get the following error on the console:

```
Not Found: /photologue/gallery/css/bootstrap.min.css
[24/Aug/2018 13:42:52] "GET /photologue/gallery/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 7311
```

This is odd to me, because I am almost certain that the css file is present.

This is the django code including the CSS file (taken from the photologue example project):

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

The resultant HTML is:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

No matter where I put the CSS file, I get a 404 error.

I have photologue templates in myapp/templates/photologue, because for whatever reason that's what worked.

The HTML I have there works fine, but the CSS just won't load. Not in it's own subfolder in the photologue templates directory, not as a subfolder in the myapp tempaltes directory, not as standalone files, not when I put them in the static folder....I've tried putting them in every possible location and reloading the site, and it makes no difference.

What can I do to make my template, which loads correctly, load and see CSS files?

edit: settings.py : https://pastebin.com/kRj21j3m

Comment: Hi Jake, could you provide me with your `settings.py` file and also what your browser inspector error is saying...

Comment: @MichealJRoberts Adding settings.py to my question, not sure what browser inspector is, I'm just using the output from when I use manage.py and runserver

Comment: When you open your page in Chrome/Safari et al. you can right click and chose the "Inspect Element" option, navigate to console and see what errors are being logged. It looks to be that it's just looking at a relative path - could you try the below in my answer - very confident this should fix things. :)

Comment: Hi Jake - where is you 'static' directory in your project... i.e., where in relation to the `settings.py` file is this directory?

Comment: @MichealJRoberts I have 'parent' app, jake_site which has settings.py, and another app for my actual site called home, which in installed in that settings.py. So, settings.py is in /venv/jake_site/jake_site/ and static dir is at /venv/jake_site/home/static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your server is looking for your css file here:

`/photologue/gallery/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Where it doesn't actually exist, hence the 404 error (file/page not found).
If you're using the base Django instructions for setting up a project, it is highly likely that your static files are found here:

`/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Please make sure you have the following in your `settings.py` file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

I also suspect that you may want this in your `base.html` file (or whichever template you're extending from):

```
{% load static %}
```

And then this in your template's head:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Micheal. When I made the change to the template, using the last line, I get the error : "Invalid block tag on line 8: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Comment: Hi Jake - see additional lines in my answer - this should fix your issue (the static tag not being loaded).

Comment: @JakeRankin Excellent :) If you can accept the answer it would be great - be great that the community can have this for reference.